# BigDecimal.setScale works wrong

Tags: java, android, rounding, bigdecimal

Here is my rounding function:

```
return new BigDecimal("4.780").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
```

From my view result should be 4.8, but it returns me 4.78.
Can somebody explain why?

Comment: What is `places`?

Comment: sorry places = 2

Comment: So thats your answer. `places` sets the scale of the BigDecimal. If you want 4.8 set `places` to 1.

Comment: It doesn't 'work wrong' unless you show *why* it is wrong, and you certainly have not done that.

Comment: Thank's for explanation. Now it's more clear. But i need to have next gradation 1.00, 1.50, 2.00

How to solve it with setScale?

Comment: Clearer than ***what***? You asked for two decimal places: you got two decimal places. What else did you expect? And why?

Comment: If you want to round it to the nearest half: multiply by 2, round, divide by 2.

Comment: @AndyTurner No. Set the scale to what you actually require, and the rounding mode. The rest is done for you. And HALF_UP is not the same as 'nearest half'.

Comment: @EJP how do you set the scale if you want to round to the nearest 0.5?

Comment: @AndyTurner He doesn't. He wants to round HALF_UP. It's right there n the code. You comment lacks relevance.

Comment: @EJP "But i need to have next gradation 1.00, 1.50, 2.00" looks to me like those are rounded to nearest 0.5s; or the unstated inputs just happen to be numbers that round to 0.5 gradations when rounded to 2dp. The first option seems more probable to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it says in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

> If zero or positive, the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point

So, if you set it to 2, there will be 2 digits to the right of the decimal point.